# How to take the date automatically from the xtrascheduler to an other form

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using devexpress xtrascheduler in that i need to get the date n the next form while clickin on a particular date on the xtrascheduler

for example if i am clicking on a cell having  date 02-06-2010 then when an other form is opening it shud take that date...Is it possible..

Comment: please consider to reply my answer. Worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is possible. Just take xtrascheduler value before opening new page, and set 
DateTime date;

Go to other form's code. you have a line like

```
public MyForm()
{
InitializeComponents();
}
```

add this lines too, and declare a variable at global, and set it to incoming date like,

```
DateTime incomingDate = new DateTime(); // This is in the global

public MyForm(DateTime date)
{
incomingDate = date;
InitializeComponents();
}
```

so now, when you tried to open your new form, the datetime parameter will be asked like,

```
MyForm frm = new MyForm(date);
frm.Show();
```

---------- second way

Form FirstForm = Your main form

Form SecondForm = Your second form which date will be transferred to this form

At form SecondForm:

```
public SecondForm(FirstForm x) // Request first form to opening
{
InitializeComponents();
}
```

set your datetime value to a variable in FirstForm. Lets say

```
// located global of your FirstForm
public DateTime abc = yourDateTime;


declare new FirstForm at SecondForm global like:

    public FirstForm myFirstForm; // this is in the second form global
```

at this part use this:

```
public SecondForm(FirstForm x)
{
InitializeComponents();
myFirstForm = x; // So now you can reach myFirstForm.abc which is your dateTime
}
```

just send this parameter in the first form before opening

```
SecondForm frm = new SecondForm(this);
frm.Show();
```

Scheduler Control

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

using DevExpress.ExpressApp;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions;
using DevExpress.Persistent.Base;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Scheduler.Win;
using DevExpress.Persistent.Base.General;
using DevExpress.XtraScheduler;

namespace HowToAccessSchedulerControl.Module.Win {
   public partial class SchedulerController : ViewController {
      public SchedulerController() {
         InitializeComponent();
         RegisterActions(components);
      }

      private void SchedulerController_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
          if(View.ObjectTypeInfo.Implements<IEvent>())
            View.ControlsCreated += new EventHandler(View_ControlsCreated);
      }
      void View_ControlsCreated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         // Access the current List View
         ListView view = (ListView)View;
         // Access the View's List Editor as a SchedulerListEditor
         SchedulerListEditor listEditor = (SchedulerListEditor)view.Editor;
         //  Access the List Editor's SchedulerControl  
         SchedulerControl scheduler = listEditor.SchedulerControl;
         // Set the desired time to be visible
         if (scheduler != null)
            scheduler.Views.DayView.VisibleTime =
               new TimeOfDayInterval(new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0));
      }
   }
}
```

and also see [this information might help you](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2814) and there are [properties you need](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1749)

Comment: hii serkan first of all sorry for the delay in reply..but the code is not working it is not taking the particular date

Comment: @amk its not problem. This is the best way to transfer values between forms. I am editing my reply, there is a second way

Comment: hello serkan i have tried the second way too but its still not working.I ll explain the scenario.actualy i didnt get the idea about"your DateTime".In my case i need to get the date  from the xtrscheduler to the form that i have created.may be am asking too much..but help me please

Comment: First of all, What is your question exactly? How to get value from xtrascheduler or How to pass variable to the new form from old form?

Comment: my question is how to get value from xtrascheduler

Comment: OK I've installed Dev Express. But cant find XtraScheduler tool. Can you show me your code, and exact component name?

Comment: u need to install Devxpress v2010 vol 1.In that the controler used is scheduler control.u will be geting deatils from the demo.

Comment: Ok I found the answer. Editing my answer, check pls :)